# Как можно включать закрытый ноутбук Honor?

Tags: bios, ноутбук

Использую ноутбук как стационарный ПК - к нему подключены монитор, клавиатура и мышь. Сам ноутбук стоит вертикально за монитором, в закрытом положении. Мне нужно найти способ как его включать не открывая крышку, например с внешней клавиатуры.

Гуглил что в BIOS бывает настройка Power Management Setup с опциями Any Key или Hot Key, но у себя такой не нашел.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуй клавиатуру с кнопкой power.

Comment: "Wake on AC". Если есть такая опция, то ноутбук можно включать выключателем на колодке питания.